# Prolog more result in query

Tags: prolog

I have this rules and facts - easy.

```
alergicky(novotny, mleko).
alergicky(novotny, korysi).
alergicky(cerna, lepek).
alergicky(cerna, ryby).

obsahuje(kapr, ryby).
obsahuje(krupice, mleko).
obsahuje(chleba, lepek).
obsahuje(chobotnice, korysi).

neji(F,C):-alergicky(F,X),obsahuje(C,X).
```

And now I ask and prolog give me this.

```
2 ?- neji(novotny,X).
X = krupice
```

-But I need two results, becouse true is X = chobotnice too.

Please how can I ask and prolog give me right result?

Comment: Press `;`, or Tab, or Space...

Answer (score 0):

If you want all results at once, you can use `findall/3` as well.

```
?- findall(X, neji(novotny, X), Y).
Y = [krupice, chobotnice].
```

Otherwise Boris' comment on your post is what you need.